# Form validation validate only the first field

Tags: javascript, html, css

Empty error message show only 1st div ....without all div (name, password)...why?

```js
//empty checking 
function checkEmpty(field_id) {
  var check_all = document.getElementById(field_id);
  if (check_all.value == "" || check_all.value == null) {
    displayWarning(field_id, check_all.parentNode.id, "you can't leave this empty")
    return false;
  }
}

//display warning error message
function displayWarning(element_id, parent_div, message) {
  var x = document.getElementById(parent_div).querySelectorAll(".error_msg");
  if (x.length == 0) {
    var para = document.createElement("p");
    para.setAttribute("class", "error_msg");

    var error_msg = document.createTextNode(message);
    para.appendChild(error_msg);

    document.getElementById(parent_div).appendChild(para);
    document.getElementById(element_id).className += " error_brd";
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="form_main" method="post" onsubmit="radioValidation()">
  <div id="f_name">
    <label for="name" id="name_label">Name:</label>
    <div id="input_error_section">
      <input type="text" class="name_inC" id="name_in" placeholder="Shaon Hossain" onblur="checkEmpty('name_in'); nameValid('name_in')">
      <!--<div id="error_div">2222</div>-->
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What if call the displayErrorMessage twice?

Comment: Did you debug your code?

Comment: problem solved...yaa...tnx

Answer (score 0):

first what's this `nameValid('name_in')` in your `html`? right now it's not pointing to anything and is returning an error.

second your code is working as it suppose to do, you're checking if array `x` is empty and if `true` you're creating a `textNode` a `p` setting attributes etc.. 
and then adding that paragraph to `div .input_error_section` you didn't instruct your code to do more!
or am I missing something?!